# Python: Read whitespace separated strings from file similar to readline

Tags: python, file-io

In Python, `f.readline()` returns the next line from the file `f`. That is, it starts at the current position of `f`, reads till it encounters a line break, returns everything in between and updates the position of `f`.

Now I want to do the exactly the same, but for whitespace separated files (not only newlines). For example, consider a file `f` with the content

```
token1 token2

token3                            token4


         token5
```

So I'm looking for some function `readtoken()` such that after opening `f`, the first call of `f.readtoken()` returns `token1`, the second call retuns `token2` etc.

For efficiency and to avoid problems with very long lines or very large files, there should be no buffering.

I was almost sure that this should be possible "out of the box" with the standard library. However, I didn't find any suitable function or a way to redefine the delimiters for `readline()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to create a wrapper function; this is easy enough:

```
def read_by_tokens(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        for token in line.split():
            yield token
```

Note that `.readline()` doesn't just read a file character by character until a newline is encountered; the file is read in blocks (a buffer) to improve performance.

The above method reads the file by lines but yields the result split on whitespace. Use it like:

```
with open('somefilename') as f:
    for token in read_by_tokens(f):
        print(token)
```

Because `read_by_tokens()` is a generator, you either need to loop directly over the function result, or use the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get tokens one by one:

```
with open('somefilename') as f:
    tokenized = read_by_tokens(f)

    # read first two tokens separately
    first_token = next(tokenized)
    second_token = next(tokenized)

    for token in tokenized:
        # loops over all tokens *except the first two*
        print(token)
```

Comment: Note that this is a generator (+1), so it works like `for line in f` rather than `f.readline()`

Comment: @HenryKeiter: You should really use the file as an iterator anyway instead of using `.readline()` calls, but yes.

Comment: Of course. I just wanted it to be clear since he's specifically asking about `readline`. Your edits have made my comment superfluous though :)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! The read calls will be in different contexts, so I won't use the it as an iterator.